# elastich search strange behaviour, looking for prefix of whole phrase but got prefix for every word

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I my index lets say I have field field named "full_name". I'm doing following query:

```
{
"query":{
    "bool":{
        "must":[
            {
                "wildcard":{
                    "full_name":"ab*"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"size":50
}
```

And it return values that fits exactly, for example:

```
"full_name" : "abrakadabra"
```

But also I receive things like this:

```
"full_name" : "kad abra"
```

Wildacrd "ab*" fits word "abra" and therefore I have "full_name" : "kad abra" . How can I avoid it, and search only for first word prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard analyzer, which is applied by default to strings, generates a term for each word. So, "kad abra" is indexed as two terms "kad" and "abra", and your query finds the second term. If you want to search full_name always as a phrase, you should index it with custom analyzer with keyword tokenizer and lowercase filter. Alternatively, you can just index this field as not_analyzed if case is meaningful in your terms.

Comment: is there any way around it, with using some proper query, or i need to index my data again?

Comment: I cannot think of any reasonable way around it. If this field is stored, you could create a script filter to check every record. However, such a query would be really slow on a large index.